# Enable OpenSSL NULL-SHA and NULL-MD5 ciphers

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm trying to force OpenSSL to user NULL-MD5 or NULL-SHA ciphers.

Output of SSLScan:

```
Preferred TLSv1.2  0 bits    NULL-SHA                     
Accepted  TLSv1.2  0 bits    NULL-MD5                     
Preferred TLSv1.1  0 bits    NULL-SHA                     
Accepted  TLSv1.1  0 bits    NULL-MD5                     
Preferred TLSv1.0  0 bits    NULL-SHA                     
Accepted  TLSv1.0  0 bits    NULL-MD5
```

I tried this:

```
openssl s_client -cipher "NULL-SHA" -connect 192.168.1.1:4444
```

But I'm always getting `SSL alert number 40` error.

If I try

```
openssl s_client -tls1 -cipher "NULL-SHA" -connect 192.168.1.1:4444
```

I'm getting `No ciphers enabled for max supported SSL/TLS version` error.

If I follow request in Wireshark I can see that it's not sending NULL ciphers in Cipher Suite field.

I tried to compile OpenSSL with `enable-weak-ssl-ciphers`, `enable-ssl2` and  `enable-ssl3`, but that didn't help too:

```
./config --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.0.22 \
--openssldir=/etc/ssl \
shared enable-weak-ssl-ciphers \
-Wl,-rpath=/opt/openssl-1.0.22/lib \
enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3
```

I'm not sure if NULL cipher is supported with TLS1, TLS1.1 or TLS1.2:

```
$openssl ciphers -v NULL
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA      TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
AECDH-NULL-SHA          TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-SHA256             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA      TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-MD5                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=MD5 
PSK-NULL-SHA384         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
PSK-NULL-SHA256         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
PSK-NULL-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
```

Any suggestions what is not working? Is there a specific way I need to compile or use different parameters in my commands for NULL ciphers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I wanted to use the ciphersuite **NULL-SHA256**, I didn't try yours.

I finally succeeded to make a connection with the tools **openssl s_server** and **openssl s_client** after recompiling and using **OPENSSL_1_0_2**

Comment: Did you gave all 3 commands to enable NULL_SHA256 ? ./config  enable-weak-ssl-ciphers, enable-ssl2, enable-ssl3,enable-ssl1. Please let me know , currently i am using 1.1.1g - in which i could not see PSK_NULL_SHA256 and i would like to use  TLSv1.2

Comment: Finally, if I remember well, I was able to make in work with the openssl version 1.1.1. We need to use ` void SSL_CTX_set_security_level(SSL_CTX *ctx, int level);` , set the `level` variable to 0. This function was not present in 1.0.2, that is why ...

Comment: You could also use  void SSL_set_security_level(SSL *s, int level);    see doc : https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html

Comment: And if you want to use the openssl command line : `openssl s_client` or `openssl s_server` you need to patch it with the function that I give you before.